# Software to grab website to clickable images (pages renders)

Tags: web, hyperlink

Does anyone know a tool/app that grabs website to clickable images at once?

I need to make real websites mockup for portfolio purposes. I don't want to grab offline HTML/CSS version (e.g. SiteSucker). I just want locally browsable renders. I've already managed to grab renders (there are several apps in the field like: Page Booth, BrowseShot, Papparazzi! etc.), but making them clickable manually feels like a little bit daunting task.